# Configure OpenEJB for testing - Add other projects EJB to classpath

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, openejb

I have a big project, which has a lot of sub-projects.

For testing, I'm using OpenEJB, and it works pretty well.

But now, in one sub-project, I also need an EJB that is in another sub-project.

Is it possible to force OpenEJB to load other sub-projects EJBs? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by adding the dependencies of the projects I needed with test scope in my pom.xml.